# Wordpress "Edit Post" Page Break

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Today I got a new issue. Its weird because my site is working previous month but when I open Admin Panel 2 days ago, it looks buggy.

---

First of all, I see many JS ERRORS in the console log.

Secondly, When I tried to edit the product with ID 508, Edit page open for product ID 1. I also tried with other products but same problem happened

```
http://localhost/piratto-old/wp-admin/post.php?post=540&action=edit
http://localhost/piratto-old/wp-admin/post.php?post=528&action=edit
http://localhost/piratto-old/wp-admin/post.php?post=416&action=edit
```

I tried with above URLs but all URL open edit page for **product ID 1**

What I tried to solve issue:

1. Deactive and Delete all plugins and switch to default theme but not work at all.
2. I also migrated to two different servers and also on my LOCALHOST but not solved

Also what I note:

When I start **WP_Debug** then I got some *ACCESS LOG* in *WAMP SERVER*

```
::1 - - [24/Apr/2018:11:19:45 +0530] "GET /piratto-old/wp-admin/post.php?post=540&action=edit HTTP/1.1" 200 670608
::1 - - [24/Apr/2018:11:19:51 +0530] "POST /piratto-old/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 257
```

Comment: Did you try a fresh install of Wordpress? When you migrated servers, or on the original server.

Comment: I tried with fresh installation

Comment: Try to deactivate plugin one by one and try refreshing your page after you deactivate each plugin. If error goes away, you will at least come to know if there is problem in any plugin. Do the same with theme. Deactivate child(if any), refresh. Main theme also. May be this will help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @PreP for your answer but as I already mentioned in question this doesn't work.

**What I did is:**

***I changed the Core Wordpress***. I installed a fresh WordPress of same version and then delete its database and Import the old Database in that.

---

Import Old Database have many **PROS**

*Like when you install your plugins in new WordPress it automatically gain the old contents.
Same For Themes*

---

> **To conclude issue resolved :D**